# How do cryptocurrency exchange services generate disposable / sub-addresses?

Tags: address-generation

I am developing my cryptocurrency exchange service. The first problem - how to distinguish clients from each other? It seems to me that other services have solved this problem by generating something like a one-time address for each client - and then this problem is 100% solved. I found an article about generating disposable addresses for monero. But what about bitcoin? Tell me please where I can read about it? Or about other the top 10 cryptocurrencies. Interested in automatic generation, or api integration with some services. Thank you!

Comment: See [BIP-32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki) for one way to *deterministically* create multiple addresses in a hierarchy that could provide for multiple customers. The diagram there shows accounts at depth 1.

Comment: Does one of these answer your question? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/42763/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/113551/5406

Comment: I don't know if there is much more to be said than yes, generate a new address for each customer. Generating new addresses is a very cheap operation, and one that literally every Bitcoin related wallet service, software, or API can easily do for you.